# What is a contero?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, palabras-raras

*Contero* is a [rare word](https://www.definiciones-de.com/Definicion/de/contero.php). I found its definition:

> #### [contero](https://dle.rae.es/?w=contero)
>
> m. *Arq*. Moldura en forma de cuentas como de rosario, puestas en una misma dirección.

but I can't find any pictures illustrating what exactly this is. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's also called ["contario"](https://books.google.es/books?id=m8vwjUomhg8C&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=contero+arqueologia&source=bl&ots=zWZLgmhWyp&sig=ACfU3U2_BdCdeA35EptngdQNsThkwZ23_A&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0lMmy46boAhURmxQKHa4uDc0Q6AEwBHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=contero%20arqueologia&f=false).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of **contero** which can be seen a few centimeters below the "column capital" (*capitel* in Spanish) looking like a "*rosario*"

> Capitel del Museo Arqueológico Nacional de Aquileia
>   AMAN076: capitel jónico-itálico que pudo haber pertenecido al monumento funerario de
>   Tampia, hija de Lucio. A destacar la concepción del **contero** y muy
>   especialmente, la manera de resolver todos los elementos de la zona
>   del equino y el diseño de las volutas, netamente itálicas.

https://flic.kr/p/9bRL6E

[image]

In general "contero" is something like this:
[image]

> contero: moldura que suele llevar dos o tres cuentas estrechas y una larga.  Adorno arquitectónico formado por pequeños relieves en serie, semejantes a las cuentas de un rosario.

This last definition and the sketch can be found [here](http://www.crisol.cult.cu/otros/enciclopedia_manzanillo/datos/articulo_549.htm)

Comment: You can find other examples [here](http://marcelodelcampo.blogspot.com/2019/08/capiteles-del-museo-arqueologico.html?m=1).

Comment: Thanks @Charo Lovely capitals 

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to look for a 'rosario'? 'Rosario' is a kind of prayer, it consists of several 'Ave María', 'Padre Nuestro' and other prayers, a rosario consists of 5 'misterios', and each 'misterio' has 9 'Ave Marías' and some 'Padre Nuestros'. A 'rosario' is also a tool to count the 'Ave María' and other prayers in the rosario. It is a thread with some small round balls, and every time that you pray an 'Ave María' you are supposed to move your fingers to another ball.

Picture of a rosario in here: https://pixers.uk/stickers/rosario-40954057.

As a rosario is a contero, that's the format that you are looking for, some thread with balls, or wooden sticks with loose balls can do as well.

Comment: La definición que pone es _Arq. Moldura en forma de cuentas como de rosario, puestas en una misma dirección_. Lo que busca es foto de la moldura (_Parte saliente de perfil uniforme, que sirve para adornar o reforzar obras de arquitectura, carpintería y otras artes_), no de un rosario.

Comment: My point exactly.